# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_4 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 5000)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a project where I need to segregate the sleep data and its labels.
But I am stuck with the error mentioned above.

As I am new to the machine learning side I would be highly grateful if someone can help me out with how can I resolve this issue.

I have implemented a model using the following code:

```
EEG_training_data = EEG_training_data.reshape(EEG_training_data.shape[0],   EEG_training_data.shape[1],1)
print(EEG_training_data.shape)# (5360, 5000, 1)
EEG_validation_data = EEG_validation_data.reshape(EEG_validation_data.shape[0], EEG_validation_data.shape[1],1)
print(EEG_validation_data.shape)#(1396, 5000, 1)

label_class = (np.unique(EEG_training_label))
num_classes = label_class.size # num_classes = 5

#define the model using CNN
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size= 16, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(None,5000, 1)))  # #input_shape=(5000, 1)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

#Summary of the model defined:
model.summary()

#Define loss function
model.compile(
                      loss=  'categorical_crossentropy', # 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(), tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(), 'accuracy'])

#one Hot Encoding
y_train_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(EEG_training_label, num_classes) 
print('New y_train shape: ', y_train_hot.shape)#(5360, 5)

y_valid_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(EEG_validation_label, num_classes)
print('New y_valid shape: ', y_valid_hot.shape)#(1396, 5)

# apply fit on data
model_history = model.fit(
                            x=EEG_training_data,
                            y=y_train_hot, 
                            batch_size=32,
                            epochs=5,
                            validation_data=(EEG_validation_data, y_valid_hot),
                             )



model_prediction = model.predict(EEG_testing_data)
predicted_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=EEG_testing_label.argmax(axis=1), predictions=model_prediction.argmax(axis=1)).numpy()
print(predicted_matrix)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not experiencing your issue with the code you have provided. Try executing the following code, that should work as expected. If that is the case, double check that the shapes of all your data, i.e. `EEG_training_data`  etc. are like the ones below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

EEG_training_data = np.ones((5360, 5000, 1))
EEG_validation_data = np.ones((1396, 5000, 1))
EEG_training_label = np.random.randint(5, size=5360)
EEG_validation_label = np.random.randint(5, size=1396)

label_class = (np.unique(EEG_training_label))
num_classes = label_class.size
print(num_classes)  # prints 5

#define the model using CNN
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size= 16, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(None, 5000, 1)))  # input_shape=(5000, 1)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(8, padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

#Summary of the model defined:
model.summary()

#Define loss function
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(), tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(), 'accuracy'])

#one Hot Encoding
y_train_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(EEG_training_label, num_classes) 

print('New y_train shape: ', y_train_hot.shape)  #(5360, 5)

y_valid_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(EEG_validation_label, num_classes)
print('New y_valid shape: ', y_valid_hot.shape)  #(1396, 5)

# apply fit on data
model_history = model.fit(x=EEG_training_data,
                          y=y_train_hot, 
                          batch_size=32,
                          epochs=5,
                          validation_data=(EEG_validation_data, y_valid_hot),
)

model_prediction = model.predict(EEG_validation_data)
predicted_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=EEG_validation_label.argmax(axis=1), predictions=model_prediction.argmax(axis=1)).numpy()
print(predicted_matrix)
```

Comment: Hello ClaudiaR, Thank you for your response. I have edited my post with the information about the shape of my data. In my case, EEG_training_data has a shape: (5360, 5000, 1), also the value y_train_hot that I have assigned to y has a shape: (5360, 5), where 5 is num_classes. So, it is the same shape that you have entered in the model.fit(). Do you think including one hot encoding is the reason for the problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some code you should try executing. You correctly used one-hot encoding. Let me know if the code copy pasted from above works for you too. I suspect you may have some bug elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ClaudiaR. I have found my mistake and understood the corrections provided by you.